# impdp: ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, impdp

I'm trying to import a large database, and after a while I get:

> ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'

I know this has been asked before, but I can't find a clear answer other than "**increase the size**".

Tablespace is like this:

[image: Tablespace]

It's an ***autoextend***, but that is meaningless since it can't grow past **32GB**, therefore I can't "**increase the size**".

Does **impdp** try to do everything in one transaction?

I don't care what it's putting in **UNDOTBS1**, if I lost everything in there that would be fine, I just want the import to run successfully.

Can I flush it out?, Is there an **impdp** option that I can use to make it not crash after 2 hours of hoping it won't crash?

There is plenty of disk space.

Any advice appreciated

Comment: If there's "plenty of disk space", why is it that the tablespace "can't grow past 32GB"?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dbaparadise.com/2017/01/what-happens-to-undo-tablespace-during-datapump-import-and-how-to-fix-it/)?

Comment: @mustaccio because of the overall poor quality of the software:
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/975815/tabelspace-does-not-extend-when-it-is-autoextensible
"even if you have a datafile set to autoextend, it is limited to 2^22 blocks in size. At an 8k block size, this means 32GB"

Comment: A tablespace defined as a `BIGFILE` (or single file) tablespace can have a datafile as large as 128TB depending on support of the underlying OS or storage. That said, if the link provided by @mustaccio doesn't help (and it sounds like it *should* help), the answer to growing a tablespace limited to 32GB per file is simply to *add another file* using the `ALTER TABLESPACE` command.

Comment: are you importing into existing tables?

Comment: @miracle173 yes, with `table_exists_action=TRUNCATE`